# how to generate the name of a custom control in it's design definition property

Tags: xpages

I would like to generate the name of the custom control in it's design definition property. how should i do that?

i tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"> 

<xp:panel> 
<%=this.pageName %>
</xp:panel> 
</xp:view>
```

because this.getPageName() gives you the name of custom control name on custom control's main level.

but that does not work there.

Answer (score 1):

After few tests it seems you can read only custom properties.

Because you write design definition to some specific custom control, you can use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"> 
<xp:panel> 
My control name
</xp:panel> 
</xp:view>
```

I am aware of harder maintainability with copypasta coding style.